# Change column type on sql conditionally?

Tags: mysql

I want to conditionally change column type in sql to `Boolean` if it is `Integer` in mysql. I know the way to update if column name is given but because of the huge number of columns,thats not feasible. Basically in the example below

```
Alter table TableName Alter Column ColumnName nvarchar(100)
```

I want to apply conition to list of `ColumnName`

Comment: Write code to generate the alter statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the commands in this way (but pay attention to values contained in existing columns):

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME,' ALTER COLUMN ', COLUMN_NAME,' bit;') AS cmd FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE 1=1
AND data_type = 'int'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'FILES';
```